# C++ initialize const static vector dynamically

Tags: c++, vector, static, initialization, constants

I would like to initalize a `static const std::vector` in class `Foo` to `{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n}` where `n` is known at compile time based on the value of `Last` in the `enum` below. The goal is for `Foo::all` to contain all the values of the `Fruit` enum.

In `foo.h`:

```
enum Fruit { Apple, Orange, Banana, ..., Last };

class Foo {
public:
    static const vector<int> all;
};
```

In `foo.cpp`:

```
// initialization of Foo::all goes here.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `boost::irange`:

```
auto range = boost::irange(0, n + 1);
const vector<int> Foo::numbers(range.begin(), range.end());
```

Answer (score 6):

As a third option:

```
namespace {
  std::vector<int> create();
}
const std::vector<int> Foo::all = create();
```

And `create()` can do anything it likes, even using `push_back()` for each element, because the `vector` it creates isn't const.

Or you could make `create()` a `constexpr` function using [`<index_tuple.h>`](http://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h)

```
#include <redi/index_tuple.h>

namespace {
  template<unsigned... I>
    constexpr std::initializer_list<int>
    create(redi::index_tuple<I...>)
    {
      return { I... };
    }
}

const std::vector<int> Foo::all = create(typename redi::make_index_tuple<Last>::type());
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `n` is small enough and you use a compiler, which supports `c++0x` or `c++11`, just spell it out

```
const std::vector<int> Foo::all{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n};
```

Fixed as per @Jonathan's explanation.

Comment: The idiomatic C++11 way would not use the `=` sign.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Is there a difference apart from the same deal as `BigInt i = 5;` and `BigInt i(5);`, which I've never really seen strong opinions for?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ok, I didn't know that. g++ accepts either one.

Comment: With the `=` sign it's equivalent to `vector<int> v = vector<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n}`. @chris the difference is that one requires a non-explicit constructor and an accessible copy constructor (which obviously `vector` has, but not all types do.) e.g `std::unique_ptr<int> p = new int;` is not valid, but `std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);` is valid.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Ok, I was just wondering if it was just that or something else on top of it in this specific case. I know direct initialization is usually preferable :)